# Cannot read 'data' of undefined in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to access data in an array, but it does not display it and sends an error instead :

[image: Error]

And this is my code :

```
function formatErrorHtml(arrayToDisplay, error_name) {
  var stringFormat = "";
  for (var i = 0; i <= arrayToDisplay.length; i++) {
    // console.log(arrayToDisplay[i].data.error);
    var error = arrayToDisplay[i].data.error;
    if(error === error_name) {
      stringFormat += "Hello" + "<br />";
    }
  }
  return stringFormat;
}
```

This is the structure of the array displayed in console.log :
[image: Array structure]

I'd like to access to data in the green rectangle.

When I display `arrayToDisplay[i].data.error` in console.log it works. But it does not in the for the loop.

You can see the result of the console.log there:
[image: Array displayed]

How can I access data without error?
Is `arrayToDisplay[i].data.error` not correct ?

Any idea would be appreciated, many thanks.

Comment: If you could, please edit  *your actual code* as text into your question - images of code *alone* are [tedious and difficult](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) to work with and debug. It forces those who would otherwise love to help you to [transcribe your image](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) first, which is a waste of time.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've just edited it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the <= to <
I believe the last one looks for dataToDisplay[9]

Answer (score 1):

[Accessing array elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Accessing_array_elements)

> JavaScript arrays are zero-indexed: the first element of an array is at index 0, and the last element is at the index equal to the value of the array's length property minus 1. Using an invalid index number returns undefined.

Your loop is iterating for the item (in the last iteration) which does not exist in the array:

Change `i <= arrayToDisplay.length`

To `i < arrayToDisplay.length` or `i <= arrayToDisplay.length - 1` in the for loop.

Comment: Thank you for the information, I did not expect that to be the issue !